Question about Proposition 2.4, Chapter 5 in Do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry"
I am having trouble understanding the following step in Proposition 5.2.4 in Do Carmo, highlighted below:

My guess is they show $(d exp_p)_{tv}(tw) = t(d exp_p)_{tv}(w)$. However, I have been unable to prove this fact, coming up only with:
$$
(d exp_p)_{tv}(tw) = \frac{d}{ds}(exp_p(1, p, tv + tws))
$$
and
$$
t(d exp_p)_{tv}(w) = t \cdot \frac{d}{ds}(exp_p(1, p, tv + ws))
$$

The step you are asking for follows from the general fact that the differential of a map between manifolds is a linear mapping between the respective tangent spaces.
